# How to return the highest one if given a string with name and value but not a json dictionary by using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing, max

I have a string like this (this is a result i got from a rest API, however it's not a Json array, it is a string):

```
[Alex:1, Rose:12, Howdie:72, Lina:1, Emily:1, Pac:15, Virus:1, Love:18, Brie:11]
```

Now what I need is to return the name with highest value (in this example this would be the name *Howdie*). I am thinking of building a function to look for the highest number and return that name. However, I am not sure if there is any way to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: That's not a valid array, and if it's a string, it's not valid anything and you'd have to make your own parser

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a way? Please try to implement it instead of asking for a complete solution, this is not what this site is meant for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a string like this:

```
const input = "[Alex:1, Rose:12, Howdie:72, Lina:1, Emily:1, Pac:15, Virus:1, Love:18, Brie:11]";
```

We firstly need to import it to a valid js array:

```
const parsed = input
      .replace("[","")
      .replace("]","")
      .split(", ") //get key value pairs
      .map(pair => pair.split(":"));//get 2d array
```

So now we could sort the parsed after the value descending:

```
parsed.sort(( [nameA,valueA], [nameB,valueB] ) =>
   valueB - valueA
);
```

To get the biggest one ( the first one ):

```
const result = parsed[0];
//key and value:
const key = result[0], value = result[1];

//OR both at once

const [key,value] = parsed[0];
```

*the upper code is ES6, you may use `var` instead of `const` and a regular function instead of `=>` if you want to support old browsers*

If you dont think that the upper code works, click [here](http://jsbin.com/dafepunuku/edit?console) ;)